# How to write argparse in python using abstract base class

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, abc

I am new in python, and trying to use Parser for command line options, arguments and subcommand.

My command should look like as:

if store in s3 or swift then:

```
$snapshotter S3 [-h] [-v] --aws-access-key-id AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                         --aws-secret-access-key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
                         --s3-bucket-name S3_BUCKET_NAME
                         {list,backup,restore} ...
$snapshotter Swift [-h] [-v] --swift-url SWIFT_URL
                         --key SWIFT_KEY 
                         --password PASSWORD
                         {list,backup,restore} ...
```

how to start writting parser and also will be changed the arguments for subcommands (list, backup, restore) depends on S3/SWIFT.

Please someone provide me hint to start the code.

Comment: argparse supports subcommands out of the box.  What are you having trouble with exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want 2 levels of subcommands, one that distinguishes between `S3` and `Swift` and another between `list`, `backup` etc.

This structure does that:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp1 = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd1')
ps3 = sp1.add_parser('S3')
ps3.add_argument('--aws-access-key-id')
# more
sp2 = ps3.add_subparsers(dest='s3cmd')
list3 = sp2.add_parser('list')
list3.add_argument('-f')

psW = sp1.add_parser('Swift')
psW.add_argument('--switft-url')
# more 
spW = psW.add_subparsers(dest='s3cmd')
listW = spW.add_parser('list')
listW.add_argument('-g')

args=parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Some sample runs:

```
1311:~/mypy$ python stack37930737.py -h
usage: stack37930737.py [-h] {S3,Swift} ...

positional arguments:
  {S3,Swift}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

1311:~/mypy$ python stack37930737.py S3 -h
usage: stack37930737.py S3 [-h] [--aws-access-key-id AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID]
                           {list} ...

positional arguments:
  {list}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --aws-access-key-id AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

1312:~/mypy$ python stack37930737.py S3 list -h
usage: stack37930737.py S3 list [-h] [-f F]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -f F

1315:~/mypy$ python stack37930737.py S3 --aws 234 list -f 34
Namespace(aws_access_key_id='234', cmd1='S3', f='34', s3cmd='list')
```

The main `parser` implements the `S3/Swift` subparser protocol.  Each of those subparsers implement their own version of the `list/backup,etc` choice.

Comment: Thanks, It is useful for me